# Dell Studio 1558 BIOS Update Failed

Tags: laptop, boot, bios

I recently tried to downgrade my Dell Studio 1558 Laptop from A12 BIOS to A11 Version and flashing was in progress then after a while the display showed a message that the computer will be turned off to protect the components from overheating. After this the computer just won't start, the power led doesn't turn on, fan doesn't work, display doesn't work, etc. When I press the power button the led indicator near it which shows when the battery is charging blinks couple of times and that's it.

I tried the Phoenix WinCrisis tool to recover the BIOS but no luck - I followed the procedure, removed the battery, connected bios flash usb, pressed the end key and then connected the power cord and waited for few seconds but no activity and then tried pressing the power button but still no activity.

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

It's dead, Jim.

If the process did not finish, the BIOS is not recoverable. You will have to replace the motherboard.

Comment: Hi Randolph, I've read in many forums, where users of various brands of laptops faced similar problem where the bios upgrade didn't finish and then they recovered it via WinCrisis, I followed the procedure but it isn't working for me, I'm sure the motherboard is fine if only I could get to flash it with bios software, I know it'll work again, any ideas?

Comment: It depends how far gone the BIOS is. You have no guarantee that it even wrote anything to the chip before locking up, so for all you know, the BIOS is completely wiped. Nothing short of replacing the BIOS chip can resurrect the board in that case.

Comment: Thanks Randolph for your help. As I mentioned earlier there is a way to install the BIOS software but unfortunately it isn't working for me, I was hoping someone who has recovered their Dell Studio 1558 laptop's bios could help me out.